# Can't autoload Tank Auth with the Codenigitier

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, tankauth

I was able to implement the Tank Auth library with my website, but have an issue when I move the autoload of the library from the Auth controller to the codeignitier autoload library.

As you can see below I have commented out the auto load of the tank Auth library, if I load it here then everything works fine.

```
class Auth extends MY_Controller
    {
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

       $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
      //$this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('security');
 //     $this->load->library('tank_auth');
        $this->lang->load('tank_auth');
}
```

THIS is now I load it in the codeignitier, as you can see pretty straight forward

$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation','email','upload','tank_auth');

this is the controller that I have defined

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{

```
      public $layout;
 public function __construct()
  {

//this sets where the header and footer file is loacated
    parent::__construct();
    $this->layout = 'layout/master';

  }
```

}

The error I get when autoloading is The model name you are loading is the name of a resource that is already being used: users. Obviously it looks like its trying to create the object twice.

Why would autoloading before the Auth library cause this issue, when its auto loaded anyway in the Auth controller, maybe I'm missing some vital piece of understanding of codignitier.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try renaming the library file? Besides, there is no harm in loading the library in the _construct.

Comment: I want to make the Tank Auth fnctions available to other controllers so thought this was the best way to load the file, maybe I was wrong. Why would renaming file work, I'm not saying it won't work.

Comment: Renaming the file didn't make any difference. Actually if I autoload from my new controller I get same error

Comment: Once you autoload the library in autoload.php, again you are trying to load the same file in the another controller or model, this will show following error.

The model name you are loading is the name of a resource that is already being used: users

To avoid that i will just recommend that do not load that library ANYWHERE in the full application once you autoload that particular library.

Comment: Hi Reccur, thats the thing. i have reduced the project down to the two controllers. Home and Auth say, so the only place the load of the Tank_auth library is happening is in the autoload. I find it hard to believe that its an issue with Tank auth code, otherwise loads would have the issue.